# problema con ireport al intentar guardar el reporteview

Tags: java, ireport

Estoy intentanto guardar mi reporte generado en el jasperview en .PDF, como en la imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego de darle en guardar el documento PDF no es generado, luego el compilar me aparece este error:

> Qt: Untested Windows version 10.0 detected!
>   Qt: Untested Windows version 10.0 detected!
>   Qt: Untested Windows version 10.0 detected!
>   Qt: Untested Windows version 10.0 detected!
>   Qt: Untested Windows version 10.0 detected!
>   Qt: Untested Windows version 10.0 detected!
>   Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/itextpdf/text/DocumentException
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.view.save.JRPdfSaveContributor.save(JRPdfSaveContributor.java:117)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.view.JRViewer.btnSaveActionPerformed(JRViewer.java:1233)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.view.JRViewer$3.actionPerformed(JRViewer.java:763)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>       at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
>       at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
>       at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
>       at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
>       at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>       ... 40 more`

Por cierto, dejo mi código de mi button para mayor información:

```
        try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conexion;
        conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://EJEMPLO/DBEJEMPLO?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull", "root", "SistemasDaca");


        JasperReport reporte = null;
        String path = "src\\reportes\\derechohabiente.jasper";
        //CARGO EL REPORTE AL OBJETO
        reporte =  (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(path);
        // LLENANDO EL REPORTE
        JasperPrint jprint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte, null,conexion);  
        // CREAMOS LA VISTA DEL REPORTE
        JasperViewer view = new JasperViewer(jprint,false);
        // LE AGREGAMOS QUE SE CIERRE SOLO EL REPORTE
        view.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        // INICIALIZAMMOS LA VISTA DEL REPORTE
        view.setVisible(true);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(frmPrincipal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: Comprueba si la dependencia itext está incluida.

Comment: Hola francisco! te refieres al .jar? Porque si, si lo tengo

Comment: Kevin, te recomiendo revisar esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28394971/7977890) en StackOverflow en inglés.

Comment: Francisco, todo este tiempo estuve utilizando el iText-2.1.0, luego de leer la respuesta en ingles, conclui que debo agregar el itext en la ultima version, pero aun asi tengo el problema con un exception: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/itextpdf/text/DocumentException

Comment: Kevin, qué versión de itext estás usando actualmente?